# Regular Expression to search longest word in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

I have a string:

```
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
```

Is there a way to find the longest word in a string using regex? This will prevent me to split the string into words and then looping through all of them.

Possibly if I can use it in JavaScript as:

```
str.search(/regex/); // should return 28 (position of word 'consectetur')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Regex is not the best option to solve this problem here. You're better off with the split string method.

Comment: Do yo mean it's not possible using regex, or regex way will not be efficient than split string method? Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to do with regex only since regex does not compare anything. It just matches the first found match that conforms to the pattern. If there are more matches, then there are language-specific methods to get them, and other string methods to compare strings and their lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, this is not possible with a regex only solution. And nearly all solutions I can think of; would still need you to slice the string to words. The smallest solution you can use would be:

```
var x = str.match( /\w+/g );
var y = x.map( function(t) { return t.length } );
var z = str.indexOf( x[y.indexOf( Math.max.apply(Math, y) )] );
```

Comment: To add a regex to the mix: `var x = str.match(/\w+/g)` - it would also discard the comma after "amet".

Answer (score 0):

Check this Update [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/pw0pqg4g/4/)

JS Code:

```
 var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
    str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z\s]/g, " ");
        var maxoffset = 0, maxlen=0, wordoffset = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str[i] == " ") {
                wordoffset = i + 1;
            }
            if (i - wordoffset + 1> maxlen) {
                maxoffset = wordoffset;
                maxlen = i - wordoffset + 1;
            }
        }
        return str.substring(maxoffset, maxoffset + maxlen);
```

Comment: It looks to me a nice solution. Will it be efficient than split string loop method?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here is my solution that I did not see posted.

Obv this is the fastest solution posted, albeit a little late.

Accomplish the task using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```
     text.match(/\w+/g).reduce( (p,c) =>
       c.length > p.length ? c : p
     ,'');
```